# Ansible regexp that will change only found string instead of whole line

Tags: regex, docker, ansible

I'm trying to setup playbook that will setup some docker services. I'm trying to pass some variables that are obtained by vars_prompt to docker-compose file.

```
replace:
        path: files/docker-compose.yaml
        regexp: 'SERVER_IP'
        replace: '{{ ip_address }}'
```

Destination file

```
    environment:
      (...)
      SERVER_IP: 'SERVICE_IP_ADDR' 
      (...)
```

Right now such task replace whole line with ip_address variable

expected result

```
environment:
      (...)
      SERVER_IP: ip_address 
      (...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the modules *replace* or *lineinfile*, a more robust solution would be updating the dictionary. For example, given the file

```yaml
shell> cat files/docker-compose.yaml
environment:
  k1: v1
  SERVER_IP: 'SERVICE_IP_ADDR'
  k3: v3
```

and the below variables

```yaml
  dc_file: "{{ playbook_dir }}/files/docker-compose.yaml"
  ip_address: 10.1.0.10
```

declare the dictionary *dc_update*

```yaml
  dc_update:
    environment:
      SERVER_IP: '{{ ip_address }}'
```

Include the content of the file into the dictionary *dc*

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: "{{ dc_file }}"
        name: dc
```

and declare the below variable

```yaml
  docker_compose: "{{ dc|combine(dc_update, recursive=true) }}"
```

This gives the updated configuration

```yaml
  docker_compose:
    environment:
      SERVER_IP: 10.1.0.10
      k1: v1
      k3: v3
```

Writes the updated configuration into the file

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: "{{ dc_file }}"
        content: |
          {{ docker_compose|to_nice_yaml(indent=2) }}
```

Running the play with the *`--diff`* options gives

```yaml
TASK [copy] *******************************************************************
--- before: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-176/files/docker-compose.yaml
+++ after: /home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-667065tpus_pfk/tmpnkohmmiz
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 environment:
+  SERVER_IP: 10.1.0.10
   k1: v1
-  SERVER_IP: 'SERVICE_IP_ADDR'
   k3: v3

changed: [localhost]
```

---

```yaml
shell> cat files/docker-compose.yaml
environment:
  SERVER_IP: 10.1.0.10
  k1: v1
  k3: v3
```

---

Notes:

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    dc_file: "{{ playbook_dir }}/files/docker-compose.yaml"
    ip_address: 10.1.0.10
    dc_update:
      environment:
        SERVER_IP: '{{ ip_address }}'

    docker_compose: "{{ dc|combine(dc_update, recursive=true) }}"

  tasks:

    - include_vars:
        file: "{{ dc_file }}"
        name: dc

    - debug:
        var: docker_compose

    - copy:
        dest: "{{ dc_file }}"
        content: |
          {{ docker_compose|to_nice_yaml(indent=2) }}
```

- You can use modules *replace* and *lineinfile*. See the examples below on how to get the expected result by matching the key `SERVER_IP`, the value `SERVICE_IP_ADDR`, or both. All options below give the same result

```yaml
--- before: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-176/files/docker-compose.yaml (content)
+++ after: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-176/files/docker-compose.yaml (content)
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 environment:
   k1: v1
-  SERVER_IP: 'SERVICE_IP_ADDR'
+  SERVER_IP: '10.1.0.10'
   k3: v3

changed: [localhost]
```

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    dc_file: "{{ playbook_dir }}/files/docker-compose.yaml"
    ip_address: 10.1.0.10

  tasks:

    - replace:
        path: "{{ dc_file }}"
        regexp: SERVICE_IP_ADDR
        replace: "{{ ip_address }}"
      when: replace_by_value|d(false)|bool

    - replace:
        path: "{{ dc_file }}"
        regexp: "SERVER_IP:.*"
        replace: "SERVER_IP: '{{ ip_address }}'"
      when: replace_by_key|d(false)|bool

    - replace:
        path: "{{ dc_file }}"
        regexp: "SERVER_IP: \\'SERVICE_IP_ADDR\\'"
        replace: "SERVER_IP: '{{ ip_address }}'"
      when: replace_by_kv|d(false)|bool

    - lineinfile:
        backrefs: true
        path: "{{ dc_file }}"
        regexp: "^(.*)\\'SERVICE_IP_ADDR\\'$"
        line: "\\1'{{ ip_address }}'"
      when: lineinfile_by_value|d(false)|bool

    - lineinfile:
        backrefs: true
        path: "{{ dc_file }}"
        regexp: "^(\\s*)SERVER_IP:.*$"
        line: "\\1SERVER_IP: '{{ ip_address }}'"
      when: lineinfile_by_key|d(false)|bool

    - lineinfile:
        backrefs: true
        path: "{{ dc_file }}"
        regexp: "^(\\s*)SERVER_IP: \\'SERVICE_IP_ADDR\\'$"
        line: "\\1SERVER_IP: '{{ ip_address }}'"
      when: lineinfile_by_kv|d(false)|bool
```

Answer (score 0):

After some test I've found solution for that.

```
replace:
        path: files/docker-compose.yaml
        regexp: (\s+)\'SERVICE_IP_ADDR\'(\s+.*)?$
        replace: \1'{{ ip_address }}'\2
```